# How to create many similar ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I would like to make a simple ViewController with two or three Buttons and labels. When I press the Button it plays an audio file.

I want to make hundreds of this similar screen, what is the best way to create it? (I am currently creating it with MainStoryBoard.)

For each page I would like to make small changes such as Buttons sizes ,Buttons numbers, label texts and audio files.

Drawing text bubbles or using xib file might be good, but I am not sure what I should.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: why would you want to make hundreds of pages?

Comment: Use single storyboard view controller and create multiple instance of it...

Comment: @Tj3n umm What do you mean by create multiple instance of it? Do I need to create buttons and labels with code?

Comment: No, I mean you can create a another instance of your viewcontroller in code, then use code to configure the small changes with your property in code

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good idea to create hundreds of view controllers.  Yet, if you have to, just create a base view controller and then subclass it every time you create a new view controller.

Comment: @Tj3n   well,,, I am creating buttons and labels with drag and drop from object library. Then I am connecting IBOutlet with audio files...Can I make changes to these with code?

Comment: You can, button size and color can be change easily in code, you just need to create the base viewcontroller that contains the pre made buttons and labels

Comment: I see, but how can I do with audio files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to have your own class for this UIViewController as a base class that has buttons, labels, etc.

Then use Factory Design pattern to generate the inherited UIViewController class which allows you to do some tweak that fits you need.

[Factory Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method)

```
BaseViewController {
    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button1;
    UILabel *label1;
}

ChildViewControllerA : BaseViewController {
    UIButton *button3
}

ChildViewControllerB : BaseViewController {
    UIButton *button4
}

Factory : NSObject {
    + (BaseViewController)generateChildViewController: (int) type {
        switch (type)
            case 0:
                return [[ChildViewControllerA alloc] init];
            case 1:
                return [[ChildViewControllerB alloc] init];
     }
}

Main {
    - (void)createThreeViewControllers {
        BaseViewController *vc1 = [Factory generateChildViewController:0];
        vc1.button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        BaseViewController *vc2 = [Factory generateChildViewController:0];
        vc2.button2.center = cgpointmake (100, 150);
        BaseViewController *vc3 = [Factory generateChildViewController:0];
        vc3.label1.text = @"vc3 test";
    }
}
```

Comment: "You need to have your own class for this UIViewController" Does it mean I have to make everything with code? I am currently setting buttons, labels etc with MainStoryBoard and it would be hard to write code for each different ViewController..... :/

Comment: @rebecca87 as what I have written, you still need to create a base view controller class that you can assign it to the Viewcontroller in your storyboard. With this been done, you can save the work to edit them in the code and you still need to adjust these elements to fit your need in the code for every instances you created in any ways (e.g. Factory). It's silly to create all instances of ViewController one by one in storyboard especially they are pretty much the same, which can be solved by Inheritance.

Comment: um  "save the work to edit them in the code and you still need to adjust these" Does it mean I can copy the code and paste it to new ViewController ? I just need to make ViewController for each new page instead of creating it in StoryBoard?

Comment: @rebecca87 It means, once the new instance is generated, you can tweak its attribute later to fit your need. You can keep creating new instances in code. I will try to edit the answer so you will see

Comment: Thanks I will try to do it:)